# Custom LLD rules

Tags: zabbix

I want to monitor my pfsense's gateway in zabbix and I need your help with low-level discovery.
Currently, I have a script that return me a json object like this :

```
{
  "data":[
    {"{#GATEWAY}":"WAN_SFRGW", "{{#LOSS}}":"0.0"},
    {"{#GATEWAY}":"WAN_NUMERICABLE_DHCP", "{{#LOSS}}":"0.0"}
  ]
}
```

I have created discovery rules in my host setting:

- Name: Gateways
- Type: Zabbix agent (active)
- Key: gateways

I have nothing in `Filters`.

Then, how can I get the information in my JSON ? I tried to create an item prototype but I can't see the result in `Monitoring -> Overview`.
I want to save packets loss, associate them with an interface and made an alert if it's > X% but I don't know how do to this.
I tried some settings in item prototypes but I don't know how to debug and if it's really possible.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the JSON: it should be `{#LOSS}` instead of `{{#LOSS}}`.

Once that is fixed, you can create an item prototype, like so:

```
gateway[{#GATEWAY}]
```

From this item prototype, the following items will be created:

```
gateway[WAN_SFRGW]
gateway[WAN_NUMERICABLE_DHCP]
```

You can also create a trigger prototype like the following:

```
{host:gateway[{#GATEWAY}].min(#3)} > {#LOSS}
```

This will create the following triggers:

```
{host:gateway[WAN_SFRGW].min(#3)} > 0.0
{host:gateway[WAN_NUMERICABLE_DHCP].min(#3)} > 0.0
```

Hopefully that describes the general idea, assuming I understood your intention correctly. Of course, you need to replace `gateway[]` items with those that actually gather some data.

The process of low-level discovery is described in great detail in the official documentation at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery .

Comment: {#LOSS} is the purcentage of lost packet. Can I define a constant and do something like this `if #gateway.#loss > 20 % => send a mail alert` ?

Comment: If you wish {#LOSS} to be the constant value of an item, you can define a calculated item with key gateway[{#GATEWAY}] and {#LOSS} as the expression. You can then create a trigger prototype {host:gateway[{#GATEWAY}].min(#3)} > 20. However, I am not sure that creating constant items and changing them with each LLD is a good Zabbix practice.

Comment: Normally, LLD is only used for discovering items, rather than populating their values. Values are usually populated separately, although technically the constant approach works, too (you should verify that items keep their history though when their expressions are changed).